# Delete cascading enrollments

Tags: desire2learn, valence

How to delete user's enrollments from cascading structure of org units?
In my app I use the following path to create enrollments:

```
POST /d2l/api/lp/1.4/enrollments/
```

with request body:

```
{
 "OrgUnitId": 123,
 "UserId": 4,
 "RoleId": 5
}
```

this call creates 3 enrollments:

1. OrgUnitId=123 -> Course offering
2. OrgUnitId=124 -> Section
3. OrgUnitId=125 -> Group

So, I know only top level orgUnitId (related to Course offering). Others enrollments are created automatically.

When I try to delete enrollments I use the following DELETE call:

```
/d2l/api/lp/1.4/enrollments/orgUnits/123/users/4
```

After this call I still see "enrollments children":

- OrgUnitId=124 -> Section
- OrgUnitId=125 -> Group

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the API could handle this, but here's an alternative:

The DELETE call will return an EnrollmentData block showing the status pre-deletion:

```
{
"OrgUnitId": <number:D2LID>,
"UserId": <number:D2LID>,
"RoleId": <number:D2LID>,
"IsCascading": <boolean>
}
```

If IsCascading is true, retrieve the children using the request below, and iterate your original DELETE statement on the children OrgUnits.

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/(orgUnitId)/descendants/
```

(See http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-orgstructure-%28orgUnitId%29-descendants-)